# Do new iOS apps need to fit iPhone 6 and 6+?

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-approval

So I am developing an app for a company and am under quite a time pressure now. It is yet available for 3.5 and 4 inch. But since Apple has just released the new screenSizes, do they possibly reject the binary I upload for review if it is not made for the new sizes? Because that was the case for when 4 inch was new, I remember.

Did anybody release an app since the release of iPhone 6 and 6+ yet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty sure their junk just up scales from iPhone 4/5 sizes.

Comment: @eBrian did you upload an app since iPhone 6 & 6+ are released?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app **must** work on iPhone 6 and 6+.
You should test it (e.g. in the simulator). **If the app doesn't crash**, even though things appear somewhat disproportioned (too big), compared to other iDevices, then you have a high probability **there will be no problem**, since the scale is the same as on 4 inch devices.

You need to upload screenshots for iPhone 6 and 6+, too.

Comment: Can you provide me with the reference, where apple have declared that they wont accept the app if the app doesn't match with the iPhone 6 screen?

Comment: Hi obaid, maybe this is too late, but this is what you'd get if you don't upload the iPhone 6/6+ screenshots. iTunesConnect won't complain, but your binary will be rejected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267471/itunes-connect-what-if-i-dont-update-screenshot-for-iphone-6