# iTunes Connect - What if I don't update screenshot for iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Now that two more screensize show in iTunes Connect when you update your app. There are more screenshot size to take. My question is, do I have to upload screenshot for all sizes? What if I just upload one set of screens? Will they also show up in app store in other size devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Apple now requires you to also submit screenshots for the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. You can either take screenshots in the iPhone Simulator or simply scale up your existing screenshots (not recommended) if the app doesn't fully support the larger screen sizes yet.

If you don't submit the screenshots, you will get:

```
ITC.apps.validation.screenshot_5.5-Inch_missing
ITC.apps.validation.screenshot_4.7-Inch_missing
```

Comment: +1.  I was publishing apps for 6 months before I realized that you could take screenshots with the simulator.  I had to take screenshots of the entire screen, then precisely crop them down to the correct dimensions.  It was a dark time.  Scaling up screenshots of smaller sizes would be similarly tiresome, and could lead to lower-quality images.  Taking screenshots natively in the Simulator is the best bet.

Comment: Yep, its definitely a good tip to know ;-) Glad I could help.

Comment: It does not seem that screenshots for 6 and 6 plus are required on the submission page. So what if I don't add them? Will my user see now screenshot at all when they see the app in app store on 6 and 6 plus?

Comment: They are not required when you submit the app, but if you don't, you will get a rejection email from apple.

Comment: Hi sgonzalez I would add that you may upscale your images, BUT it should be avoided if possible,since resolution in iPhone 6/6+ is higher than other iPhones/iPods. It isn't a very important point since it will probably just pass the review unnoticed, but the screenshot should be created from the corresponding device/simulator if possible.

Comment: This information is incorrect. iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus screenshots are only required if your app natively supports that screen screen. If your app doesn't natively support that screen resolution then you do not need to add screenshots and your app would not be rejected.